# Check if an existing transactionscope is active

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope, nested-transactions

I am using:

```
public class TransactionUtils
{
    public static TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope()
    {
        var TransactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
        TransactionOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
        TransactionOptions.Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionOptions);
    }
}
```

to create all my transactions. The problem I am facing is when I nest 2 `TransactionUtils.CreateTransactionScope()` I get an error: `Time-out interval must be less than 2^32-2. Parameter name: dueTm`. I am assuming this is because it's trying to attach the child transaction to the parent one and the combined timeouts are to large.

Is there a way to tell if a newly created transaction will be a nested one so I can avoid setting a timeout?

The alternative is to pass a parameter to `CreateTransactionScope()` so I can tell it that's it's nested and not set the timeout but I would rather find an automatic way of handling it.

Comment: I think the max value it would pick would be from the machine config, do you really need the `TimeSpan.MaxValue` part ? Maybe this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963934/error-time-out-interval-must-be-less-than-232-2-parameter-name-duetm

Comment: I was thinking about this after I posted and I have changed the timeout to 30 seconds instead as this makes more sense (who would want an SQL transaction running for months? :) ). This "avoids" the issue but still nice to know I can check if a transaction is active.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's a pretty simple answer:

```
System.Transactions.Transaction.Current != null
```

This works since Framework 2.0.

I'm not sure why the other answer goes to such depths to create IL that links to nonpublic fields.

Comment: Having just investigated this (yay ILSpy)  Current can throw an exception if you are inside a transaction, AND the TransactionScope is complete.  Just so you allow for the fact that you might get an exception instead

Comment: @RogerWillcocks good catch.  I hadn't looked at the IL in a while, and I'm not sure if this was added post-2.0 framework or not.  And... I'm scratching my head wondering why it would *ever* throw an exception... However, this answer is still better than building dynamic IL to inspect non-public fields, since medium trust environments would choke harder.

Comment: Only way I could see it happening is if you called TransactionScope.Complete() then trying to use it for more transactional activity

Comment: @RogerWillcocks says `Transaction.Current` *throw an exception if you are inside a transaction, AND the TransactionScope is complete*. Any solution ***without***  `Transaction.Current` **throws an exception** ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep it is possible. I have the following code. I didn't make it myself but forgot where I got it. Kudos to the original author, but I do remember I just found it googling for it. I'm using it for .net 4.0, no idea how compatible this is with other versions (it depends on a specific class in a specific assembly).

Using the code below you can check if at some point in your code if you are executing 'inside' a transaction scope.

```
class TransactionScopeDetector {
    private Func<TransactionScope> _getCurrentScopeDelegate;

    public bool IsInsideTransactionScope {
        get {
            if (_getCurrentScopeDelegate == null) {
                _getCurrentScopeDelegate = CreateGetCurrentScopeDelegate();
            }

            TransactionScope ts = _getCurrentScopeDelegate();
            return ts != null;
        }
    }

    private Func<TransactionScope> CreateGetCurrentScopeDelegate() {
        DynamicMethod getCurrentScopeDM = new DynamicMethod(
          "GetCurrentScope",
          typeof(TransactionScope),
          null,
          this.GetType(),
          true);

        Type t = typeof(Transaction).Assembly.GetType("System.Transactions.ContextData");
        MethodInfo getCurrentContextDataMI = t.GetProperty(
          "CurrentData",
          BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
          .GetGetMethod(true);

        FieldInfo currentScopeFI = t.GetField("CurrentScope", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        ILGenerator gen = getCurrentScopeDM.GetILGenerator();
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getCurrentContextDataMI);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, currentScopeFI);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Func<TransactionScope>)getCurrentScopeDM.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TransactionScope>));
    }
}
```

Comment: See this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980337/how-to-know-if-the-code-is-inside-transactionscope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980337/how-to-know-if-the-code-is-inside-transactionscope).  While I don't know if it's the source, a comment worryingly states `CurrentData` has changed to `TLSCurrentData` in 4.5.

Comment: @Phil Cooper, How does it "wrongly state that CurrentData has changed"?  Um, yes, in Framework 4.5 it HAS changed to TLSCurrentData.  There's comments that confirm this in Framework 4.5.

Comment: @enorl76 "worryingly" (...in a way that causes unease or anxiety).  I didn't see any facts then to back it up, but at the time would explain why something I was looking at blew up and needed to be changed/fixed.